# How can I detect a click on the ActionBar title?

Tags: android, onclick, textview, title, android-actionbar

For specific customer requirement, I need to allow the user of my app ( won't be published in Market) to click on the ActionBar title to execute some actions.

I have been looking in the Android source, but I am not able to find an ID for the actionBar TextView title.

Is there a proper way to handle such clicks?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The title is non-clickable AFAIK. The icon/logo is clickable -- you'll get that via `android.R.id.home` in `onOptionsItemSelected()`. Conceivably, the title also routes this way, though they don't mention it and I wouldn't rely upon it.

It sounds like you want a `Spinner` for the user to choose the actions to execute. If so, use `setListNavigationCallbacks()`. If you want to remove the title as now being superfluous, use `setDisplayOptions(0, DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE)`.

If you want something other than a `Spinner` on the left side of the action bar, use `setDisplayOptions(DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM, DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM)` and `setCustomView()`. Note that this approach is not recommended (["Avoid using custom navigation modes in the action bar"](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/preparing-for-handsets.html)), as it may not work well with phones, particularly in portrait mode.

Another possibility would be to remove the title and use a logo instead of the icon, and in the logo have your "title" as part of the image. The whole logo should be clickable, picked up via `onOptionsItemSelected()`.

Comment: You said you can detect the the event when the user clicked on the Android ActionBar logo by adding this :


 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        //User clicked on the ActionBar logo
    }
    return true;// stop system processing
  }


But for me this does not work. Also i tried with onTouchEvent X and Y of the event, (not great...) but this does not work either.
I would appreciate if you could help me there

Comment: @OlivierM: You need to call `setHomeButtonEnabled()` on your `ActionBar` if you are running on Android 4.0 or higher. On Android 3.x, that method did not exist and was not needed.

Comment: FYI, as of 4.2.2 title and icon are treated as one element.

Comment: While I understand why you shouldn't implement your own "custom" navigation modes, how else could I set a specific type face for my title other than using setCustomView with my own TextViews in it? Not nice, really...

Comment: But in whatsapp application you'l find the title is also clickable.

Comment: Spinners (ActionBar drop-down menus) are described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown

Comment: Is it possible to both customize how the spinner (made by "setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST)" ) and also get a reference to it, in order to handle some operations on it programmatically ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: There is no supported way to get the `Spinner`. Technically, it does not have to be implemented by a `Spinner` at all.

Comment: @CommonsWare So it's best to use "setCustomView" and do things the way you want, right? I guess it's for the best.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: So long as you don't do something to cause your users to go "WTF?", sure. The risk of doing something *like* `NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST` without it actually *being* `NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST` is the "uncanny valley", where your approach differs in subtle ways that cause user angst.

Comment: @CommonsWare I only considered using NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST because I didn't know of the setCustomView, so I planned on making it look like a title&subtitle , and handle clicking myself. It was supposed to be a workaround, and the UI would (as I planned) look the same. I do this for a company that wishes to have something like WhatsApp, which makes clicking on the title customize the current group. I said my opinion that it's a bit weird, but that's their choice. Anyway, "setCustomView" works fine so there is no need for this weird workaround (which I didn't even manage to make).

Comment: remember to setHasOptionsMenu(true); in the onCreate() of fragment to make onOptionsItemSelected() work.

Answer (score 10):

//onCreate

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
//        View actionBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar_custom_view, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView);
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

//your logic for click listner
 setListenerForActionBarCustomView(actionBarView);

 private void setListenerForActionBarCustomView(View actionBarView) {
        ActionBarCustomViewOnClickListener actionBarCustomViewOnClickListener = new ActionBarCustomViewOnClickListener();
        actionBarView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title).setOnClickListener(actionBarCustomViewOnClickListener);
}
 private class ActionBarCustomViewOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {       
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.text_view_title:

                //finish();
                break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to mimic the exact way the action bar title&subtitle are shown, so that it would look like clicking on the normal ones ?

Answer (score 6):

You can set up a custom toolbar from Support Library by declaring `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>` in your layout (see [Chris Banes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26440880/241986) for full toolbar layout example).

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- We use a Toolbar so that our drawer can be displayed
             in front of the action bar -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/main_toolbar" 
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

       <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

After you can add on click listener in your activity just like to most other Views.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

If you want to capture touch events on title:

```
toolbar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            Rect hitrect = new Rect();
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN == event.getAction()) {
                    boolean hit = false;
                    for (int i = toolbar.getChildCount() - 1; i != -1; i--) {
                        View view = toolbar.getChildAt(i);
                        if (view instanceof TextView) {
                            view.getHitRect(hitrect);
                            if (hitrect.contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY())) {
                                hit = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (hit) {
                        //Hit action
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```