# How to detect a click for custom action bar?

Tags: android, custom-controls, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have a requirement where i have a icon ( not the application icon ) that needs to be on left hand side of the action bar.

I tried creating custom view but i have no clue on how to detect the click on that icon.

Other option that comes to mind is to have setIcon(mycustomicon) and handle the click events onOptionSelected method; but this method is also not being invoked and not working.

I am using actionbar sherlockholmes library. Is it because of that?

Please help me as i am stuck with this for days .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7981633/1479570) ? Seems related

Comment: You can refer below link http://stackoverflow.com/a/7981633/1441666

Comment: yes , but i am not getting on click events when i set the icon .I am not sure why .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are adding your custom view with `getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(resId)`, you need to get the newly created View object back by calling `getSupportActionBar().getCustomView()`. Then, you can set your click handler with `setOnClickListener` as you would normally do with others views.

On the other hand, if you are using one of the overloads of setCustomView that take a View as the first parameter, the first step can be omitted since you already have a View object to work with.

Here is an example for the first case:

```
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.test);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

getSupportActionBar().getCustomView().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: i Have more than one view in the action bar I have used switch (view.getId()) {
      case R.id.menu:
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Menu",
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       break;
      case R.id.textView:
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Header",
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       break;
      }
 for this but unable to set click event can u please suggest me where i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 6):

This may help you

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
            getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
            /***THis will be used to creatre a custom action bar click listener **/
            View v =getSupportActionBar().getCustomView();
           /*** sample click is a id of the view i have used in action bar view ***/
            ((Button)v.findViewById(R.id.smaple_click)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    /*****Add your click function here******/

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own "Action", like so

```
public class CustomAction extends AbstractAction
{
    public interface CustomActionListener
    {
        public void onAction(int drawable);
    }

    private CustomActionListener listener;
    private int drawable;

    public CustomAction(CustomActionListener listener, int drawable)
    {
        super(drawable);

        this.listener = listener;
        this.drawable = drawable;
    }

    @Override
    public void performAction(View view)
    {
        if (listener != null)
        {
            listener.onAction(drawable);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, add the action to the action bar.

```
CustomAction menuAction = new CustomAction(this, R.drawable.ic_menu);
ActionBar.addAction(menuAction);
```

Make sure the activity  implements CustomActionListener, in which you can do almost anything.

```
@Override
public void onAction(int drawable)
{
    // your code goes here...
}
```

I must admit I'm using a slightly modified version of [johannilsson/android-actionbar](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar/). But the main idea is to know how to use Action and AbstractAction. Check out the implementation of "BackAction" in the library.

Answer (score -1):

u don need to create a custom view jst add the item in menu layout (having required icon). Then handle onOptionSelected() and make sure are you returning **true**